# obtener el Ultimo registro de cada mes

Tags: mysql

hola tengo una duda estoy tratando de filtral una consulta de la siguiente manera con mysql:

```
SELECT a, b, d
FROM 
    mitabla
GROUP BY d;
```

Donde `d` es una columna tipo: `datetime`, la idea es traer el ultimo registro de cada mes, de ser posible. pero me trae todo.

Comment: Vos necesitas que te devuelva un solo registro con la fecha mas grande o uno por cada mes?

Comment: **la idea es traer el ultimo registro de cada mes,**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que esta pregunta tiene casi un año, pero quizá la respuesta le sirva a otra persona.

El problema es que MySQL no cuenta con las funciones de Agregado FIRST y LAST de otros motores y que efectivamente devuelven un valor del primer y ultimo registro respectivamente dentro de un GROUP BY. Las funciones MAX y MIN devuelven los valores máximo y mínimo respectivamente sin importar la clausula ORDER BY.

Ahora... si lo quieres obtener es simplemente la última fecha de cada mes (aunque no le veo mucho sentido) te serviría de la siguiente manera:

```html
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mitabla.d, '%Y%m') Mes, MAX(mitabla.d)MaxFechaHora
    FROM mitabla  
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(mitabla.d, '%Y%m')
```

Si lo que quieres es trabajar con el último registro de cada mes la única solución a nivel de SQL es algo como esto:

```html
SELECT t.* 
FROM  mitabla t JOIN 
(
    /* Esta subconsulta solo te trae la ultima FechaHora de cada mes */
    SELECT MAX(mitabla.d)MaxFechaHora
    FROM mitabla  
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(mitabla.d, '%Y%m')
) m ON t.d = m.MaxFechaHora
```

Esto solo te funciona si:

1. En el campo que es DataTime se guarda siempre la Fecha con la Hora, porque aunque si se guarda solo la Fecha quedaran mas o menos así: 2018-09-30 00:00:00 en ese caso te devolverá cualquier registro del último día de cada mes.
2. No se repite mas de un registro en el mismo segundo, porque los campos DateTime em MySQL no manejan milésimas de segundo. Si llegan a coincidir mas de un registro en el mismo YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS te devolverá al azar cualquiera de los que se repiten.

Si realmente quieres obtener el último registro dentro de un GROUP BY tienes que hacerlo por programación:
Es un poquito mas complejo, pero se puede. Si es lo que necesitas, puedo explicarte cómo hacerlo.

Comment: la idea es explicarlo aquí, para eso es la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a, b, d 
FROM mitabla
GROUP BY d
order by desc d
limit 1;
```

Mas o menos por ahi va
saludos.

Comment: la idea es traer el ultimo registro de cada mes no la ultima de todos los registros...

Answer (score 1):

Trata creando una tabla temporal anidada en la misma consulta, agrupas por mes y luego año, ordenas por fecha. Luego selecciona solo el máximo id (asumiendo que es autonumerico incremental). La tabla va a devolverte el id del último registro de cada mes y año. Usas ese id para seleccionar de la tabla original el resto de las columnas que requieres.

```
 select a, b, d  from mitabla,(SELECT Max(id), MONTH(d) as mes,YEAR(d) as ano 
    FROM 
        mitabla
    GROUP BY mes,ano order by d desc) as fechas 

    Where mitabla.id=fechas.id
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu aporte! En el sitio intentamos tener respuestas con la mayor calidad posible. La idea no es mostrar solamente un fragmento de código, sino además explicar por qué esto funcionaría. ¿Qué hace este código? ¿Por qué o cómo solucionaría el problema expuesto en la pregunta? En [answer] podrás leer algunos consejos. ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu respuesta agregando algo más de información?

Comment: me explicas que hace esto ???

Comment: Agregué la explicación.

Comment: hola en realidad lo que quiero es traer las fechas. no el id

Comment: b y d son las fechas.